# Bash writing an if statement

Tags: bash

I am new to bash and I need to write an if statement within my code however I am unsure how to write is so that if `$someVar` is found then run this else do that.  In this case `$someVar` is a file and I am not wanting to output text just run another line of code in this case creating the file.

**Code:**

```
rm /var/path/to/folder/$someVar

for i in `seq 3 253`

do

echo $ALLOCATION.$i >> /var/path/to/folder/$someVar
```

Comment: Short answer `if [[ -n $someVar ]]; then .. do your stuff .. fi` Any bash reference will explain and `man bash` will also explain the type of *conditional expressions* (or tests) available.

Comment: @Joe Have updated question

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks,  I also have updated my question

Comment: One other question -- when you say *exists* do you mean the file with the same name as the variable contents exists, or do you just mean that `$someVar` is set and is not *empty*? To test if a file with the name held by `$someVar` exists, it is `if [[ -f $someVar ]]; then ... do your stuff ..fi`. You can also just use a *compound command* to check and conditionally remove the file `[[ -f $someVar ]] && rm /var/path/to/folder/$someVar`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The latter  are you able to put it as an answer so I can make sure I have the correct formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check for the existence of `/var/path/to/folder/"$someVar"`, then you can use:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -f /var/path/to/folder/$someVar ]]; then

    rm /var/path/to/folder/"$someVar"

fi

for i in `seq 3 253`; do

        echo $ALLOCATION.$i >> /var/path/to/folder/"$someVar"

done
```

You can also use a simple *compound-command*:

```
#!/bin/bash

[[ -f /var/path/to/folder/$someVar ]] && rm /var/path/to/folder/"$someVar"

for i in `seq 3 253`; do

    echo $ALLOCATION.$i >> /var/path/to/folder/"$someVar"

done
```

**Note:** within `[[ ... ]]` you do not have to quote your variable to protect against `spaces` in the variable. In all other cases you should (as a rule of thumb).

Also, note to check whether the file is *writeable* (i.e. you have permission to remove it), you can use `[[ -w /var/path/to/folder/$someVar ]]`